# Choices for BLE to configure headless device plus OTA

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, ota

I have a headless device running Ubuntu that I want to make configurable and updatable via Bluetooth. In a secure way not opening too many back doors. Reason is the payment terminal on the device connected over Ethernet to backend system.

Settings I need to do are simple integers and some strings. BLE GATT (and GAP) looked the modern thing to do. I can get the get and set for that working via Android. Question is how to upload a 10MB firmware file from android over BLE. I tried to stay away from what I know from the past, like using serial port protocol calling a REST endpoint. Was wondering what the modern way of a file transfer is using BLE in combination with a maintenance engineer using GATT to retrieve and update settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much have changed over the last years, except for the addition of L2CAP CoC in Android 10.

Simply said, use LE Data Length Extension, set MTU to maximum allowed (517 on Android) and send either Write Without Response or Notification packets. If the devices both support 2M PHY, use that. Also a short connection interval is usually preferred. Let your Ubuntu device be master so that you can control "connection event length" in the LE Create Connection packet, to schedule as much radio time as possible to your connection.